# show alert and then go to route in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

- I created a react app and implemented two routes.
- The Page on '/'    shows a welcome message and `/pageone` shows the
  other page.
- i have button in homepage( "/" ) which is wrapped with link
  `to="/pageone"`.
- i want to show a alert "Hi Welcome" and after that only i want to
  route to the `pageone` page.

  how to achieve this? is there any way to write  a function that triggers alert and then activate the link?

Comment: Please provide the code or snippet to recreate the problem in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function called onClose and implement what you want to do before routing, but keep in mind that after routing the state of the Component will disappear if you do not mount it inside pageone component

```js
import { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       visible: true
    }
  }
  onClose = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: false });
    window.alert('Welcome to Page One')
  }

  render() {
    return(
     <Link to='/pageone' onClick={() => onClose()}>Go To Page One</Link>
    )
  }

}

export default App
```

Comment: Your answer works perfect @onuritan . i want to run a function before routing takes place after clicking. is there any way?  actually what i really want is to close the sidebar component before the route takes place. i want to run my this.onClose function on clicking after that only route needs to take place. kindly help me

Comment: Do you want if a certain condition is okey then route? else do not route kind of situation?

Comment: I have a function  onClose = () => {this.setState({visible: false,});}; i want it to run after that only i want to change my route onclicking.

Comment: Can you look the extended solution, it should make the state visible false and then alert and then routing at the end

Comment: Thankyou @onuriltan, i learn new today because of you